# Неправильное отображение кириллицы в командной строке Windows Golang

Tags: windows, golang, cmd, консоль, кириллица

Столкнулся с проблемой кириллицы в командной строке, программа удалённо выполняет команду в командной строке Windows, возвращает результат вывода командной строки  и тут приходят �������� HELP <��� �������>.

```
        package main

    import (
        "fmt"
        "os/exec"
        "strings"
    )

    func main() {
        stdout, err := exec.Command("cmd.exe", "dir","D:\\").Output()
        out = string(stdout)

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Error execute is %s\n", err)
        }

  fmt.Printf("Result %s\n", out)
    }
```

Пытался декодировать полученный вывод r := charmap.ISO8859_1.NewDecoder().Reader(f) https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/encoding/charmap, но дальше хаотичных символов не ушёл.
Как работать с русифицированной командной строкой windows?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Всем спасибо, разобрался!
Помог код https://studygolang.com/articles/18355.

```
    package main

import (
    "golang.org/x/text/transform"
    "bytes"
    "golang.org/x/text/encoding/charmap"
    "golang.org/x/text/encoding/simplifiedchinese"
    "io/ioutil"
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().Unix())
    fmt.Println(string(convert(rand.Intn(47),[]byte("golang学习"))))
}

func convert(i int, s []byte) ([]byte) {
    var reader *transform.Reader
    switch i {
    case 1:
        reader = transform.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(s), charmap.ISO8859_1.NewDecoder())
    case 2:
        reader = transform.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(s), charmap.ISO8859_2.NewDecoder())
    case 3:
        reader = transform.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(s), charmap.ISO8859_3.NewDecoder())
    case 4:
        reader = transform.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(s), charmap.ISO8859_4.NewDecoder())
    case 5:
        reader = transform.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(s), charmap.ISO8859_5.NewDecoder())
    case 6:
        reader = transform.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(s), charmap.ISO8859_6.NewDecoder())
    case 7:
        reader = transform.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(s), charmap.ISO8859_7.NewDecoder())
    case 8:
        reader = transform.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(s), charmap.ISO8859_8.NewDecoder())
    case 9:
        reader = transform.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(s), charmap.ISO8859_9.NewDecoder())
    case 10:
        reader = transform.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(s), charmap.ISO8859_10.NewDecoder())
    case 11:
        reader = transform.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(s), charmap.ISO8859_13.NewDecoder())
    case 12:
        reader = transform.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(s), charmap.ISO8859_14.NewDecoder())
    case 13:
        reader = transform.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(s), charmap.ISO8859_15.NewDecoder())
    case 14:
        reader = transform.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(s), charmap.ISO8859_16.NewDecoder())
    case 15:
        reader = transform.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(s), charmap.KOI8R.NewDecoder())
    case 16:
        reader = transform.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(s), charmap.KOI8U.NewDecoder())
    case 17:
        reader = transform.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(s), charmap.Macintosh.NewDecoder())
    case 18:
        reader = transform.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(s), charmap.MacintoshCyrillic.NewDecoder())
    case 19:
        reader = transform.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(s), charmap.Windows874.NewDecoder())
    case 20:
        reader = transform.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(s), charmap.Windows1250.NewDecoder())
    case 21:
        reader = transform.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(s), charmap.Windows1251.NewDecoder())
    case 22:
        reader = transform.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(s), charmap.Windows1252.NewDecoder())
    case 23:
        reader = transform.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(s), charmap.Windows1253.NewDecoder())
    case 24:
        reader = transform.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(s), charmap.Windows1254.NewDecoder())
    case 25:
        reader = transform.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(s), charmap.Windows1255.NewDecoder())
    case 26:
        reader = transform.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(s), charmap.Windows1256.NewDecoder())
    case 27:
        reader = transform.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(s), charmap.Windows1257.NewDecoder())
    case 28:
        reader = transform.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(s), charmap.Windows1258.NewDecoder())
    case 29:
        reader = transform.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(s), charmap.XUserDefined.NewDecoder())
    case 30:
        reader = transform.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(s), charmap.CodePage037.NewDecoder())
    case 31:
        reader = transform.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(s), charmap.CodePage437.NewDecoder())
    case 32:
        reader = transform.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(s), charmap.CodePage850.NewDecoder())
    case 33:
        reader = transform.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(s), charmap.CodePage852.NewDecoder())
    case 34:
        reader = transform.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(s), charmap.CodePage855.NewDecoder())
    case 35:
        reader = transform.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(s), charmap.CodePage858.NewDecoder())
    case 36:
        reader = transform.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(s), charmap.CodePage860.NewDecoder())
    case 37:
        reader = transform.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(s), charmap.CodePage862.NewDecoder())
    case 38:
        reader = transform.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(s), charmap.CodePage863.NewDecoder())
    case 39:
        reader = transform.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(s), charmap.CodePage865.NewDecoder())
    case 40:
        reader = transform.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(s), charmap.CodePage865.NewDecoder())
    case 41:
        reader = transform.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(s), charmap.CodePage866.NewDecoder())
    case 42:
        reader = transform.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(s), charmap.CodePage1047.NewDecoder())
    case 43:
        reader = transform.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(s), charmap.CodePage1140.NewDecoder())
    case 44:
        reader = transform.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(s), simplifiedchinese.GBK.NewEncoder())
    case 45:
        reader = transform.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(s), simplifiedchinese.HZGB2312.NewEncoder())
    case 46:
        reader = transform.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(s), simplifiedchinese.GB18030.NewEncoder())
    }

    d, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(reader)

    return d
}
```